# JPA/Hibernate seems to convert a query with an in clause into multiple queries with = clauses

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jpa

A solution we implemented in order to collect a large amount of heavy objects in reasonable time and without memory overflow (I'm speaking of objects with multiple fetchType.eager relations, to entities that themselves have eager fetched relations), was to first select ids of those objects, and then select the objects themselves based on these ids.

Coming the time to optimise our code, we noticed (using `hibernate.show_sql=true`) that the query we used to gather those objects  (`select a from A a where a.id in :ids`) is translated by JPA/Hibernate into thousands of queries of the form `select a from ...endless join list... where a.id = ?`

The question is the following:

**Why JPA/Hibernate transforms our initial query with an "in" clause into so many queries with "=" clauses. Isn't it inefficent ? If so, is there a way to prevent that ?**

Here's how the query is called in our code:

```
    Query q = this.getContext().createQuery("select a from A a where a.id in :ids");
    q.setParameter("ids", idList);
    return (List<A>) q.getResultList();
```

Comment: Which's your hibernate version?

Comment: hibernate_core is version 5.2.12.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5082504/11046080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I still can't explain why a query is generated for each ID provided in the in clause (provided in my original question), I found a solution to this problem on this blog (https://thoughts-on-java.org/fetch-multiple-entities-id-hibernate/).
The solution consists in using Hibernate's session API as follows:

```
//get session object from entity manager
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.

MultiIdentifierLoadAccess<A> multiLoadAccess = session.byMultipleIds(A.class);
List<A> aObjects= multiLoadAccess.withBatchSize(1000).multiLoad(idList);
return aObjects;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you should use [setParameterList](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-) instead of `setParameter`.
Also no need to use `select` in hibernate if you want to get the complete entity object.

```
 Query q = this.getContext().createQuery("from A a where a.id in (:ids)");
q.setParameterList("ids", idList);
return (List<A>) q.getResultList();
```

Comment: There was a confusion on the type of the query when I originaly posted my problem. 

It was a basic jpa query and thus setParameter is to be used.

Thanks for the tips about the select however, I wasn't aware of it

Answer (score 0):

If your `idList` is more that 1000 elements, you probably hit this Oracle-specific deoptimization https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9299.

One way to solve this is to break `idList` into multiple chunks, execute a query for each and concatenate the results.

Comment: it is exactly 1000 elements. I took this restriction into account and partitionned my list of id before executing the query. Had I have an idList containing more than 1000 elements, an ORA exception would occure.